# To reduce text image size in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, arabic

I have 1000 text images in the Arabic language which I have to make an apk out of.  The decently readable size is 100 kb per jpeg image which shows as 200 kb after putting in Android Studio. This makes total app size 200 mb. Is there a way I can reduce size without affecting readability and sharpness of text images. Converting to webp for text images makes it unreadable. Google docs OCR is also inaccurate.

Comment: Can i ask why you have pictures of text instead of text only?

Comment: How much text is in each image? Is it just a few words per image or several paragraphs or pages?

Comment: @Prexx : these are scanned images of a book in arabic fonts/language and ocr is not sharp enoug to get it into text and reduce the size.

Comment: @ Code-Apprentice: entire A4 sized page is covered with words and paragraphs.

Comment: If you can't reduce the jpeg Q factor anymore and can't convert them from image to text, you're kind of screwed.  You may want to consider an extention file, or downloading the images from a webserver at runtime rather than packaging them in the apk

Comment: @Gabe Sechan : What is extention file ? Webserver like real time databse firebase ? It is free for 10GB/month i.e. 10Gb divided by 200MB images = 50 downlaods per month. Then what happens when 51st user wants to download the apk, what will he encounter until firebase resets limit in the following month ?

Comment: Sorry, ther correct name is expansion file.  https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files    An up to 2GB second file that can be part of an apk but downloaded separately.